# How to produce compile error if return value is not used?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have decorated several methods with the ReSharper attribute `[MustUseReturnValue]`:

> **MustUseReturnValueAttribute**
> Indicates that the return value of method invocation must be used.

([link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#MustUseReturnValueAttribute))

It works as described and I have given it the severity "Error". All places, where a return value is not used, are being marked as an error in the IDE, but the error does not produce any build error or show up in the error list.

Is there any way to get it fail the build if a return value is not used? Or is there an alternative way to achieve it?

[image]

I do not have all ReSharper features enabled. I only have ReSharper enabled.
[image]

I have tried to enable "debugger integration", "MsBuild and NAnt" and "ReSharper build" but that had zero effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper has a CLI package that you might be able to integrate into your build process. It should obey your inspection settings. The [package is available here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools), and you can read more about the tools [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_Command_Line_Tools.html).